# module reveal prototype pattern - private variables

Tags: javascript

I am using the module reveal prototype pattern (https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-prototype-pattern), and am having trouble accessing my this variable in my prototype functions. I have this code:

```
myapp.ConfirmationWindow = function (temptype) {
    this._type = temptype;
};

myapp.ConfirmationWindow.prototype = function () {
    this._showConfirmationWindow = function (message) {
        var a = this._type; //valid
        return _showWindow("hello");    
    }

    this._showWindow = function (message) {
        var a= this._type; //invalid
    }
    return {
        showConfirmationWindow: _showConfirmationWindow
    };
}();
```

I am able to access this._type in _showConfirmationWindow(), but am not able to access this._type in _showWindow. The different is that the prototype is setting _showConfirmationWindow() as public and _showWindow as private, but why doesn't _showWindow get access to this._type. Why is this the case.

One solution I found is to pass this as an extra parameter in _showWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_showWindow` don't have a `this` reference to your instance because it's not part of `ConfirmationWindow prototype` because by returning only `showConfirmationWindow`, it never gets assigned to the prototype. You could use `call` to invoke your private functions like:

```
_showWindow.call(this, "hello")
```

Or adding a second argument to `_showWindow` like and pass the `this` reference when you invoke it:

```
_showWindow(message, self)
```

But i would prefer the first one.

Comment: Yep that's the other option. I just wanted to add a snippet with using `call`

Comment: Can you elaborate on self=this?

Comment: Nevermind got confused with another pattern, you sould use `call` or adding a second parameter where you can pass `this` in.